# Having difficulty centring text

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if I could have someone's help as I'm having difficulty vertically and horizontally centring the text in the centre of the page.

Thanks for taking the time, have a good day.

html:

```
<div class="somethingsimple">
    </p>"...I place importance on honesty and expressiveness when creating for a society that is heavily influenced by art."</p>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.somethingsimple
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-family: font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can additionally add this css-

```
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

this moves the text up by 50% of its height, so its centered vertically. http://jsfiddle.net/ym1tys16/

AND finally to align it center horizontally you can use -

```
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

For both horizontal as well as vertical centering, use transform like this -

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ym1tys16/1/)

Full snippet -

```css
.somethingsimple {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  font-family: font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="somethingsimple">
  <p>"...I place importance on honesty and expressiveness when creating for a society that is heavily influenced by art."</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add `width:100%;` to `somethingsimple` like this:

```
.somethingsimple {
    /* your current "absolute positioning" style properties */
    width:100%;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle with above codes: http://jsfiddle.net/6pwth4zv/